# QImage out of memory

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, memory

I have sub-classed QGLWidget and I show an image in it.

For small images (let's say 1200*1000) it works fine.

For bigger ones (10000 * 6000) it crashes.

```
MyGLWidget::MyGLWidget(QImage* image, QWidget *parent) : QGLWidget(parent)
{
    // ...
    _data = *image;
    _gldata = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(_data); // Crash at this point.
    // ...
}
```

Error:

```
QImage: out of memory, returning null image
ASSERT: "dst.depth() == 32" in file qgl.cpp, line 2094
```

I have 8GB of memory, the application takes max. 1GB.

What can I do?

**EDIT**

Ok, assuming that I run out of RAM, how do I catch this error?

```
try
{
    _gldata = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(_data);
}
catch(...)
{
    qDebug() << "e.what()";
}
```

It look's like it's not an exception.

Comment: Isn't this out of vram rather than ram?

Comment: @paulm I have no idea. How do I find out?

Comment: Is _data.isNull() true or false before call the convert method?

Comment: You are making x86 or x64 app?

Comment: Use something like GPU-Z to check the GPU memory load

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld false

Comment: @paulm I think you're right. I'm out of VRAM. Thanks.

Comment: How so? You saw memory was almost depleted with the working texture?

Comment: @paulm GPU load bounced a big in GPU-Z, right before it crashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're out of RAM.

And I'm not even sure QImage can handle such big images.

`converToGLFormat` doesn't allocate anything on the GPU, it just converts the image to the ARGB8888 format and with the right byte ordering, i.e. making it suitable for upload via `glTex(Sub)Image2D`, see [here](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/opengl/qgl.cpp.html#_ZN9QGLWidget17convertToGLFormatERK6QImage). In Qt 5.2 you could also consider QOpenGLTexture if you're dealing with textures, given the right GPU capabilities it may let you avoid this conversion step.

Comment: I don't think I'm out of RAM. Also, QImage can handle that big images, it works when I don't display anything, just save it.

Comment: You're asking for 240MB (10k*6k*4Bpp) of contiguous memory in a 2GB or 3GB addressable space (you are under x86; 2 or 3 depends on Windows / Linux). Do you seriously believe that's not an out of memory situation?

Comment: If you still don't believe that libc is returning NULL for a malloc (which means you ran out of memory), then run your program in a debugger with the `QT_FATAL_WARNINGS` env variable set to 1. It'll make your program crash at the QImage warning. Look at the lines immediately before, they should involve a creation of a new image. Put a breakpoint in there, rerun your program, and see why Qt is not able to allocate the image.

Comment: I've debugged as you wanted. It crashed, with this message: QImage: out of memory, returning null image. Is there any way, to catch this, I don't know what is this (not an exception).

Comment: Did you also do *all the things I've asked*? Run in a debugger and walk through Qt's code?

Answer (score 0):

There is no real error handling in `convertToGLFormat`, it just crashes with `Q_ASSERT` if you are out of RAM, or if the image doesn't have the right format.

As a workaround, you can try allocating an image with the same size as `convertToGLFormat` and if it succeeds, free the image and call the function, as it will likely succeed too, if not, just skip the image.

```
QImage dummy(_data.size(), QImage::Format_ARGB32);
if (!dummy.isNull()) {
    dummy = QImage(); // free the image
    _gldata = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(_data);
}
```

Comment: Actually, the fact that it doesn't deal with OOM is a *maybe* a bug. QImage itself has some checks. That code instead doesn't check for an allocation failure. But anyhow: Qt assumes you never ever run out of memory.